# Find all nested childs of a parent with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

So I have a table called `contains` that has the attributes `parent` and `child`

I want to select all the childs and nested childs of a certain parent. I assume I have to use a recursive function but what would be the best way to go about that in postgresql?

I am currently finding childs using `SELECT child FROM contains WHERE parent="name"`

Answer (score 1):

You have to find **all nested child**. So you should use some recursive Query. 
In PostgreSQL you can use Recursive Query to find all nested child.

the best examples that are exactly similar to your problem: 

1- [USING RECURSIVE COMMON TABLE EXPRESSIONS TO REPRESENT TREE STRUCTURES](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/131-Using-Recursive-Common-table-expressions-to-represent-Tree-structures.html)

2- [Recursive WITH Query Evaluation In PostgreSQL – Explained](http://technobytz.com/recursive-query-evaluation-postgresql.html)